# Hibernate does not insert field which is part of composite FK

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have hibernate entity with two many-to-one associations and composite foreign keys, each with 3 fields. Two fields are common for both keys. There are mapping:

```
<class dynamic-insert='true' dynamic-update='true' entity-name='...' table='...'>
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name='FaultId' type='long' column='FAULT_ID'/>
        <key-property name='RowVersion' type='long' column='ROWVERSION'/>
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name='Pot' class='Pot'>
        <column name='SMELTER_ID' not-null='true'/>
        <column name='ROOM_ID' not-null='true'/>
        <column name='POT_ID' not-null='true'/>
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name='Event' class='PotEventRef_NonGui'>
        <column name='EVENT_ID' not-null='true'/>
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name='Shift' class='TimeShift' insert='false' update='false'>
        <column name='SMELTER_ID' not-null='true'/>
        <column name='ROOM_ID' not-null='true'/>
        <column name='TIMESHIFT' not-null='true'/>
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

Code for inserting entity:

```
session.persist(entry.getName(), entry.getData());
```

where session - org.hibernate.Session, entry.getName() - String, entry.getData() - Map<String, Object>.

When i try to insert entity of this class, TIMESHIFT field is not inserted. (Shift object is set and all values are correct). What can be source of problem?

Comment: please share the code written to save timeshift objects, also the TimeShift POJO.

Comment: There are no POJO's - all entities are dynamic Map<String, Object> and mappings xml are generated at runtime. I can share mappings generated for other entities, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try by changing update value to true & by removing insert='false' in the XML.

```
<many-to-one name='Shift' class='TimeShift' update='true'>
```